# Write a plsql block to fetch distinct department ids which is assigned to employees in EMP table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Output
Dept ID:*** is Dept_name1
Dept Id:*** is Dept_name1
Dept ID:*** is Dept_name1
Dept ID:*** is not a valid ID
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an ordinary **JOIN** (with `distinct`) which will return only those departments (from the `DEPT` table) that are used in the `EMP` table.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select distinct e.deptno, d.dname
  3                  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  4                  order by e.deptno
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: ' || cur_r.deptno ||' is ' || cur_r.dname);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
Dept ID: 10 is ACCOUNTING
Dept ID: 20 is RESEARCH
Dept ID: 30 is SALES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```